# Element extraction from a list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, nltk

I have an output in the form

```
[('the', 1334),
 ('and', 919),
 ('a', 615),
 ('to', 560),
 ('i', 519),
 ('in', 317),
 ('he', 299),
 ('they', 287),
 ('was', 277),
 ('it', 276),
 ('of', 267),
 ('on', 214),
 ('you', 210),
 ('went', 206)]
```

My question is how to I select the value for a given word. For example my function looks like this:

```
def unigram(word):
    u = [' '.join(w).lower() for w in train_corrected] # I want to change train corrected to a list of sentences so I can lower every character
    u = ' '.join(u) # makes the list of sentences into one giant string
    u = nltk.word_tokenize(u) # converts the giant string back into a list of single word elements
    freq = Counter(u).most_common() # https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html
    return freq # we only want the result of the word we input into our function not the entire dict of freq
```

I want to return say

```
unigram('the') # The output of which would be 1334 from the list of tuples
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: `return Counter(u).get(word,0)` - if you query this multiple times you should cache the counter result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired result was reached using @Patrick Artner's answer. Thanks man

```
def unigram(word):
    u = [' '.join(w).lower() for w in train_corrected] # I want to change train corrected to a list of sentences so I can lower every character
    u = ' '.join(u) # makes the list of sentences into one giant string
    u = nltk.word_tokenize(u) # converts the giant string back into a list of single word elements
    freq = Counter(u).most_common() # https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html
    return return Counter(u).get(word,0) # we only want the result of the word we input into our function not the entire dict of freq

print(unigram('the')) # output = 1334 as expected
```

Answer (score 0):

I will use a list comprehension:

```
def unigram(word):
  return [x[1] for x in train_corrected if x[0] == word][0]
```

And call like:

```
print(unigram('the'))
```

Comment: Hi Wasif thanks but it didn't work I got 'list index out of range' error

Answer (score 0):

Below code block can help you. Required_string is the string for which you want associated value as per the list of tuples shown in question.

```
Required_string = 'the'
For I in output:
    If I[0] == required_string:
         Print(I[1])
```